# How to send enclose data in DELETE request in Jersey client?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have the following server-side code in Jersey 2.x:

```
@Path("/store/remove/from/group")
@DELETE
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response removeStoresFromGroup(@FormParam("storeName") List<String> storeNames, @FormParam("groupName") String groupName) {
    //......
}
```

On client side, I want to use Jersey 2.x client to send a delete request to the above web service. However, from the documentation of [Jersey client API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/WebTarget.html), I didn't find how to enclose the following data in DELETE request:

```
WebTarget webTarget = client.target("/store/remove/from/group");
MultivaluedMap<String, String> formData = new MultivaluedHashMap<String, String>();
List<String> storeName = new ArrayList<String>();
storeName.add("Store1");
storeName.add("Store2");
storeName.add("Store3");

formData.addAll("storeName", storeName);
formData.add("groupName", "Group A");

Response response = webTarget.request().accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).delete();   //The delete() method doesn't take any entity body in the request.
```

From the Jersey client API, the [`SyncInvoker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/SyncInvoker.html) class doesn't support a `delete` method with entity body as its argument. So I can only use either POST or PUT to send the data to the server like the following (but not for DELETE):

```
Response response = webTarget.request().accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).post(Entity.form(formData));
```

But I want to use DELETE request since the request is deleting some resources. How to send DELETE request with some entity data via Jersey client?

Comment: OT but normally you don't need to send an entity with a DELETE [because](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.7) "The DELETE method requests that the origin server delete the resource identified by the Request-URI". Your method reference sounds more like updating a reference then deleting a resource.

Comment: Sometimes if I want to delete some data which satisfies certain conditions, I need to pass in some parameters in the entity body of DELETE request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `DELETE` with an entity body [is not strictly forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628) but it's very uncommon and ignored by some frameworks/servers. The need of an entity body may indicate that a `DELETE` is not used as it is intended.

For instance: If a `GET /customers/4711` returns one customer and you send a `DELETE /customers/4711` the next `GET` on this resource should return a `404`. You deleted a resource **identified by a URL** like [defined in the spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.7).

Your URL `/store/remove/from/group` does not seem to identify a resource. Using identifiers like `/store/4711` or `/groups/4711` and sending a `DELETE` on them would not fit your needs because you want to "remove a store from a group" not delete a store or a group.

Assuming you have a group resource

```
{
  "id" : 4711,
  "stores" : [123, 456, 789]
}
```

and you want a result like

```
{
  "id" : 4711,
  "stores" : [123, 789]
}
```

you are not deleting anything. You are modifying a resource so `PUT`, `POST` or `PATCH` are appropiate methods. [JSON-Patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) is a good format for describing such changes. A request would look like this:

```
PATCH /groups/4711 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json-patch

[
  {
    "op" : "remove"
    "path" : "stores/1"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. It seems that `PATCH` method is not currently supported by Jersey framework. Also does Java web server like Tomcat or Jetty support HTTP PATCH method? I could use PUT request in this case since I'm modifying the resource.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have an overview which container or framework supports `PATCH`. `PUT` is a good idea but this has the downside that you need to [send the whole modified resource](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6).

Comment: Thanks. For the sake of stability, I will just use http `PUT` for now and hopefully http `PATCH` method will be officially included in later Jersey release.

Answer (score 24):

Based on the code in Jersey 2.18 version, The class `JerseyInvocation` use a predefined HashMap to validate HTTP method and its Entity as below:

```
map.put("DELETE", EntityPresence.MUST_BE_NULL);
map.put("GET", EntityPresence.MUST_BE_NULL);
...
```

That's why we got this error "Entity must be null for http method DELETE".

While, please note that it also provide a Jersey client configuration property `ClientProperties.SUPPRESS_HTTP_COMPLIANCE_VALIDATION` to determine whether to stop the rest execution or not, so here we can use this property to suppress validation in order to continue to send a `DELETE` request with Entity. e.g.

```
    ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
    config.property(ClientProperties.SUPPRESS_HTTP_COMPLIANCE_VALIDATION, true);
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
    ...
```

Comment: I have a similar need to do this, although in my case I don't actually have a body to send, but I do need to force a 'Content-Length: 0' to be sent with a DELETE. Trying this suggestion with Jersey Client 2.5.2, I get a ProtocolException: java.net.ProtocolException: HTTP method DELETE doesn't support output
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1081)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector$3.getOutputStream(HttpUrlConnector.java:267)

Comment: My attempt to override org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest#configureClient with ClientProperties.SUPPRESS_HTTP_COMPLIANCE_VALIDATION set to true was turned into a failure. There is no exception anymore but instead I'v got service response with 400.

Comment: I'm converting a server application from Play Framework to pure JavaEE and had a DELETE resource that took a JSON body. I can't just break the old API so this helped me!

Answer (score 10):

Just to note: if you use `resteasy` implementation of `JAX RS Client API`, you may use `build().invoke()`:

```
client.target("$baseUrl$restEndPoint/$entityId")
                .request("application/json")
                .build("DELETE", Entity.entity(entity, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .invoke()
```

But it does not work with `jersey`

Comment: There is validateHttpMethodAndEntity function in JerseyInvocation which validates method and entity presence. This will throw IllegalStateException

Comment: @pshirishreddy, I use resteasy implementation of JAX RS Client API. And it works.

Comment: Agreed but the OP question was related to jersey client :)

Comment: resteasy is a jersey client

Answer (score 4):

You can use `webTarget.request().accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).method("DELETE",yourEntity)` to invoke a `DELETE` with an entity in it.

Comment: When I used this method, it reports error: "Entity must be null for http method DELETE". Why is that?

Comment: Hmm I honestly wasn't expecting that.  If you look at [1] at section 9.6 you'll see that `DELETE` is meant to be URI based.  It doesn't say it can't use a body though.. [1]: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Comment: I don't see why DELETE request can't contain entity body either from the doc. But the javadoc (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/SyncInvoker.html#method)  doesn't say it cannot use DELETE as the method name either.

Answer (score 0):

I used also RESTeasy Jersey client and worked for my:

Response response = client.target(yourUrlToCall).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
.build("DELETE", Entity.entity(yourJsonDTO, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).invoke();

Is very usefull to solve some complex scenarios that are not "allowed" by normal usage of get(), delete(), etc.